# Rails bypasses javascript after re-rendering current page: how to force a GET request?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a very simple link_to "website", root_path attached to my site logo. However, when I'm on the home page, and I click the logo (which should just take me back to the current page), all of the jquery code stops working. Looking at the logs, it seems the home page is getting re-rendered by rails, instead of issuing a new GET request:

```
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered pages/_question.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered pages/_question.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered pages/_question.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered pages/_question.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered pages/_question.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered pages/_question.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered mailing_lists/new.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (11.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered mailing_lists/new.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 38ms (Views: 37.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I have no issue with it re-rendering the page content instead of redirecting (since it's the same page), but the problem is that everything in the jquery file is now ignored. I'm guessing since the page is being re-rendered, and the JS file itself isn't getting reloaded, the DOM isn't aware of the newly rendered page content.

How do I force a redirect instead of a render, or alternatively, reload the jquery so that it's tied to the newly rendered page elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably stopped working because of [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks). The documentation explains how to get around this issue. But wrap your JavaScript in the following blocks, and they should start working again:

```
jQuery(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
  # js goes here
});
```

In CoffeeScript:

```
jQuery(document).on 'ready page:load', ->
  # js goes here.
```

This happens because Turbolinks maintains the head of the HTML document, so the document.ready doesn't get fired again. It updates everything under the `body` tag. This speeds up page loads, but has that adverse side effect.

Comment: Perfect answer, fixed the issue completely!

Comment: To avoid having to do this everywhere, you can use the jquery.turbolinks gem 
https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks